# How To fectch all data on base of Language selection in SQLite

Tags: sql, sqlite

The Table Structure of below is valid to fetch all tables data on the base of language selection in SQLite or SQL.when i select data from language then i want to fetch the data of country Genders and Currency Tables.

```
Table Language 
    {   
       LanguageName 
       LangugeCode         
       [OneToMany]   
       List<TableCountries> listOFCountries  
       [OneToMany]
       List<TableCountries> listofCountries  
       [OneToMany]   
       List<TableGender> listofgender
       [OneToMany]
       List<TableCurrency> listofCurrency
    }   
    
    
    TableCountries
    {
     CountriesCode
     CountriesName
    } 
    
    TableGender 
    {
      MaleText 
      FemaleText
    }
    
    TableCurrency
    {
      CurrencyName
      Currency Code
      Currency Symbol
    }
```

Comment: Post sample data and expected results to clarify.

Comment: i Have Query to Fetch the Countrieslistdata,Gender data,And currency data fetch when on the base of language.if i select Denish language its return all data from countries in the form of danish language ,gender and currency data ,

Comment: @forpas is this table structure is good

Comment: its will fetch the data

Comment: You are using Java syntax to describe table structure. Post the table definitions with sample data and expected results. As it is your question it is not clear.